# Intercept process on Run Project Billing screen

Tags: acumatica

We're using the Run Project Billing screen to create records in AR / Invoice and Memo.

In the Invoice & Memo screen, we need the process to populate the header Customer Ord. number, along with a user field that has been added to the grid section on the 'Document Details' tab.  At the moment, the process is not doing this.

I'd like to intercept the processing action on the screen using a technique I'm familiar with, namely using an 'AddHandler':

```
[PXOverride]
protected virtual IEnumerable Items (PXAdapter adapter)
{
   PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<BillingProcess>((graph) =>
   {
       graph.RowInserting.AddHandler<BillingProcess.ProjectsList>((sender, e) =>
       {

           //Custom logic goes here

       });
   });
   return Base.action.Press(adapter);
}
```

I see no Base.Actions that remotely resembles 'Bill' or 'Bill All'.

This is obviously not exactly the code I need, but I would think this is the general place to start.

After reviewing the source business logic, I don't see any 'Bill' or 'Bill All' Actions - or any 'Actions' at all (baffling).  I see an IEnumerable method called 'items', so that's what I started with above.

Is this the correct way to go about this?

Update:  2/14/2017

Using the answer provided re: the overridden method InsertTransaction(...) I've tried to set our ARTran user field (which is required) using the following logic:

```
        PMProject pmproj = PXSelect<PMProject, Where<PMProject.contractID, Equal<Required<PMProject.contractID>>>>.Select(Base, tran.ProjectID);
        if (pmproj == null) return;

        PMProjectExt pmprojext = PXCache<PMProject>.GetExtension<PMProjectExt>(pmproj);
        if (pmprojext == null) return;

        ARTranExt tranext = PXCache<ARTran>.GetExtension<ARTranExt>(tran);
        if (tranext == null) return;

        tranext.UsrContractID = pmprojext.UsrContractID;
```

Even though this sets the user field to the correct value, it still gives me an error that the required field is empty when the process finishes.  My limited knowledge prevents me from understanding why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Run Project Billing screen, captions of **Process** and **Process All** buttons were changed to **Bill** and **Bill All** respectively in BLC constructor. 
Process delegate is set for **Items** data view within the BillingFilter_RowSelected handler:

```
public class BillingProcess : PXGraph<BillingProcess>
{
    ...

    public BillingProcess()
    {
        Items.SetProcessCaption(PM.Messages.ProcBill);
        Items.SetProcessAllCaption(PM.Messages.ProcBillAll);
    }

    ...

    protected virtual void BillingFilter_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        BillingFilter filter = Filter.Current;

        Items.SetProcessDelegate<PMBillEngine>(
            delegate (PMBillEngine engine, ProjectsList item)
            {
                if (!engine.Bill(item.ProjectID, filter.InvoiceDate, filter.InvFinPeriodID))
                {
                    throw new PXSetPropertyException(Warnings.NothingToBill, PXErrorLevel.RowWarning);
                }
            });
    }

    ...
}
```

As code snippet above confirms, all records in the **AR Invoice and Memos** screen are created by instance of the PMBillEngine class. Below is code snippet showing how to override `InsertNewInvoiceDocument` and `InsertTransaction` methods within the PMBillEngine BLC extension:

```
public class PMBillEngineExt : PXGraphExtension<PMBillEngine>
{
    public delegate ARInvoice InsertNewInvoiceDocumentDel(string finPeriod, string docType, Customer customer,
        PMProject project, DateTime billingDate, string docDesc);

    [PXOverride]
    public ARInvoice InsertNewInvoiceDocument(string finPeriod, string docType, Customer customer, PMProject project,
        DateTime billingDate, string docDesc, InsertNewInvoiceDocumentDel del)
    {
        var result = del(finPeriod, docType, customer, project, billingDate, docDesc);
        // custom logic goes here
        return result;
    }

    [PXOverride]
    public void InsertTransaction(ARTran tran, string subCD, string note, Guid[] files)
    {
        // the system will automatically invoke base method prior to the customized one
        // custom logic goes here
    }
}
```

**Run Project Billing** process invokes `InsertNewInvoiceDocument` method to create new record on the **AR Invoice and Memos** screen and `InsertTransaction` method to add new invoice transaction.

***One important thing to mention:*** overridden `InsertNewInvoiceDocument` and `InsertTransaction` methods will be invoked when a user launches Run Project Billing operation either from the processing **Run Project Billing** screen or from the data entry **Projects** screen.

For more information on how to override virtual BLC methods, see **Help** -> **Customization** -> **Customizing Business Logic** -> **Graph** -> **To Override a Virtual Method** available in every Acumatica ERP 6.1 website

Comment: I tried to use the InsertTransactions overridden method, but this did not work.  See my edited original post...

Comment: The only possible way to assist further with this request is by debugging your customization. Obviously, that will require a support case.

Comment: This has been solved by Ruslan - the fault was in my duplicating DAC fields in both an extension library and a code window in the customization project.  Thanks, Ruslan!...